# How do I add a polymorphic class in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm

I am trying to make an application for a restaurant in django; I have to create a menu for different types of items, and all of those different types of items have to essentially be **a product**, so that I can add that product to a user's corresponding cart. Here are my menu items:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Product(models.Model):
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10)

class Pizza(Product):
    pizzatype = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    extras = models.TextField(max_length=50)
    size = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Subs(Product):
    name = models.TextField(max_length=64)
    size = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class DinnerPlatters(Product):
    name = models.TextField(max_length=64)
    size = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Pasta(Product):
    name = models.TextField(max_length=64)

class Salads(Product):
    name = models.TextField(max_length=64)
```

As can be seen, I tried deriving the models for different types of menu items from a single model **Product**, but while running `makemigrations`, I get the following message on the terminal:

```
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'product_ptr' to dinnerplatters without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
```

I tried googling the solution to my problem, but couldn't find an approriate solution.

I am new to Django and this is my first application, so any help or any other method on how to approach my problem would be kindly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As your models inherit from the Product's model, you are using Multi-table inheritance. Now that Multi-table inheritance automatically creates OneToOneField as classname_ptr between inheritance model and base model, your models which is inherit from product's model has product_ptr field. As your model has product_ptr field, you should add default value for existing rows which is save before by you.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance

Comment: Thanks for answering  ; according to your answer and the docs, I tried adding the following line to every class that inherits from the ```Product``` class: ```product_ptr = models.OneToOneField(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, parent_link=True, primary_key=True, default = None)```. Now, my ```makemigrations``` runs, but I now get the error ```django.db.utils.IntegrityError: The row in table 'orders_pizza' with primary key '1' has an invalid foreign key: orders_pizza.product_ptr_id contains a value '1' that does not have a corresponding value in orders_product.id.``` on running ```migrate```.

Comment: product_ptr = models.OneToOneField(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, parent_link=True, primary_key=True, null=True, blank=True) could you try this ?

Comment: On doing this, I got this on all the models: ```orders.DinnerPlatters.product_ptr: (fields.E007) Primary keys must not have null=True.HINT: Set null=False on the field, or remove primary_key=True argument.``` . On trying null=False or removing primary_key=True, I get the same Integrity error as last time: ```django.db.utils.IntegrityError: The row in table 'orders_pizza' with primary key '1' has an invalid foreign key: orders_pizza.product_ptr_id contains a value '1' that does not have a corresponding value in orders_product.id.```.